# Не работает Visual Composer?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет, скачал плагин с их офф сайта, установил через плагины wordpress - плагин ставится, но не работает - при попытке создать новую страницу - постоянно крутится значок загрузки.

Comment: Смотрите ошибки в консоли браузера. Потом отключите все плагины, сметните тему на стандартную. Так найдёте источник проблемы.

Comment: @KAGGDesign спасибо, отрубил все плагины и он запустился, сейчас буду поочередно запускать, и смотреть в каком плагине проблема